# How to Establish Communication between Fragment's Adapter and New Fragment?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, adapter

**Fragments**

I had created Tabbed Activity with two tabs.

[Fragment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZk1i.png)
Fragment 1 saves data to sqlite database

[Fragment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHNyd.png)
Retrieves all data and shows in recycler view

Problem: When the user clicks **View User Button** the user details should be visible on NewFragment on full screen.But i have no idea about PASSING DATA WITH FRAGMENT TRANSACTION

Comment: Have you tried using Intent ?
You can google your way out of this one I'm sure :)

Comment: By intent i can open the new fragment but how to get the particular users data???

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) :)

Comment: thanks your link is useful i tried with intents it is not working.I want to communicate between 1st Fragment's recycler view adapter and 2nd Fragment.While using interfaces i get this error:Class Cast Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data during fragment transaction using **Bundle** is the good solution.